# create multiple xmls from xsl transformation and place data into those xml's based on the tag attributes of source xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to create different xml files based on language name using xsl 2.0. In my input xml, here there are only 2 languages, "en" and "es".

1. All the "en" based persons will go to en.xml and
2. All the "es" based persons will go to es.xml and
3. All the person who have both "en" and "es" will have to go to both en.xml and es.xml.

**My Input XML:**
source xml is about the list of persons, their addresses and languages

```
<persons>
    <person name="Alice">
        <Addresses>
            <Address type ="personal">
                <language name = "en">
                </language>
            </Address>
            <Address type ="business">
                <language name = "en">
                </language>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </person>
    <person name="Bob">
        <Addresses>
            <Address type ="personal">
                <language name = "es">
                </language>
            </Address>
            <Address type ="business">
                <language name = "es">
                </language>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </person>
    <person name="Stacy">
        <Addresses>
            <Address type ="personal">
                <language name = "en">
                </language>
            </Address>
            <Address type ="business">
                <language name = "es">
                </language>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </person>
</persons>
```

### **output file en.xml will have:**

all the persons containing language attribute value = "en" should go to the en.xml file. In this case, both Alice and Stacy will need to go to en.xml

```
    <person name="Alice">
        <Addresses>
            <Address type ="personal">
                <language name = "en">
                </language>
            </Address>
            <Address type ="business">
                <language name = "en">
                </language>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </person>
        <person name="Stacy">
        <Addresses>
            <Address type ="personal">
                <language name = "en">
                </language>
            </Address>
            <Address type ="business">
                <language name = "es">
                </language>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </person>
```

### **output file es.xml will have:**

all the persons containing language attribute value = "es" should go to the en.xml file. In this case, both Bob and Stacy will need to go to es.xml

```
    <person name="Bob">
        <Addresses>
            <Address type ="personal">
                <language name = "es">
                </language>
            </Address>
            <Address type ="business">
                <language name = "es">
                </language>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </person>
    <person name="Stacy">
        <Addresses>
            <Address type ="personal">
                <language name = "en">
                </language>
            </Address>
            <Address type ="business">
                <language name = "es">
                </language>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </person>
```

**My XSL so far:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//persons">
       <xsl:variable name="filename"
             select="concat('allpersons/',//persons/person/Addresses/Address/language/@name,'.xml')" />
       <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
       <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml">
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:result-document>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Solution should not contain static matching of attributes like "en", "es".. beacause there are lot of languages. Any Help is well appreciated?

*References:*
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipmultxsl/index.html

Comment: minor question: Instead of putting the Language Element under Address as a ChildNode, put it as an Address Attribute.

Comment: I couldn't not be able to do that.. as the source xml can't be changed in any way as its being generated from a different system...for the solution, i tried a lot on looping through but still no help in getting the right output..

Comment: refer to @MartinHonnen answer, probably more of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="persons">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="person" group-by="Addresses/Address/language/@name">
    <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person/Addresses">
  <xsl:if test="Address/language/@name = current-grouping-key()">
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure you really want to create those result files without a root but if you want a root change the `persons` template to

```
<xsl:template match="persons">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="person" group-by="Addresses/Address/language/@name">
    <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
      <persons>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </persons>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Martin -Thanks for the input.  But, After the transformation, es.xml will not have Adress type = "personal" and language name="en"  which should be there as well.  In between, the <person name="Stacy"> .....</person> all data should be there in the es.xml as in the source xml.

Comment: It looks like my first attempt filtered too much of the data, mzjn has already posted a corrected stylesheet, I will correct my code too in an edit.